# CSS media query not working, not sure why

Tags: css, responsive-design, breakpoints

I have the media queries defined below. When I view it in 800x1280, it uses the mobile CSS. When I view it in 980x1280, it uses the portrait tablet CSS. It looks like, to me, in 800x1280, it should use the portrait tablet CSS. Any idea why it's not?

FYI - I'm testing it using the Responsive Design View in the Firefox browser.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:680px) and (max-width:1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="tabletportrait.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:679px)" href="smartphone.css" />
```

Comment: not seeing issues, maybe it's worth to try it on chrome mobile emulator